# MySQL Adding & Multiple Columns On Select

Tags: mysql, sql, select, left-join

My database looks as follows

Table Name: Order Details

```
id       oid      pid   pquantity  pprice
--------------------------------------
  1       1       5        2       10
  2       1       6        3       5
  3       1       7        1       20
  5       2       8        1       5
  6       2       9        1       5
  7       3       5        5       10
```

Table Name: Orders

```
id       odiscount oshipping
----------------------------
  1       5       5        
  2       0       5        
  3       0       5
```

I want to get the invoice value for each order. `(pquantity*pprice)-odiscount+oshipping`. The tricky part is that each order can have multiple entries in order details. So I am unable to figure out how to take care of that. The end result should be

```
oid   total
1     55
2     15
3     55
```

I tried this using the following SQL but I am unable to figure out how to take multiple rows in order details into account.

```
SELECT SUM((orderdetails.pprice*orderdetails.pquantity) - orders.odiscount + orders.oshipping) FROM orders LEFT JOIN orderdetails ON orderdetails.oid = orders.id GROUP BY orders.id
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you can do this without even using a subquery:

```
SELECT SUM(od.pquantity*od.pprice) + AVG(o.oshipping - o.odiscount)
FROM Orders o
INNER JOIN OrderDetails od
    ON o.id = od.oid
GROUP BY o.id
```

**Demo here:**

## SQLFiddle

Comment: I agree that this is probably the way to go, but I'm very puzzled by the attitude towards comments.

Comment: @Strawberry Sagi routinely dumps a ton of comments on my answers, creating a conversation over nothing, with the hopes that his answer will appear more pristine, and therefore more correct, than everyone else's.  Commentary: this tactic seems to work really well (though I don't use it).

Comment: LOL? First of all, you've tagged the person that comments on more answers than any of us(Which nothing wrong with that) . I didn't even answer questions for the past two weeks so rest assure that I don't have any routine of dumping comments and hoping my answer with be the accepted one. The reason my answers are accepted is only one - they are usually first, and when they are not, they wont get accepted. Chill man.

Answer (score 3):

You could group the `order_details` query first, and only then join it on the `orders` table:

```
SELECT sum_details - odiscount + oshipping
FROM   orders o
JOIN   (SELECT   oid, SUM(pquantity * pprice) AS sum_details
        FROM     order_details
        GROUP BY oid) d ON o.id = d.oid
```